# Tauri Redirect URI Schema

Tags: rust, protocols, tauri

I'm building a Tauri app and would like to set up OAuth integration with Google. To do so, I will need a URI for the oauth callback, but Tauri is unclear how to configure the schema possibly using [this](https://docs.rs/tauri/1.2.0/tauri/struct.Builder.html#method.register_uri_scheme_protocol) method or with the `WindowUrl`?

How can I add a URI to my Tauri app so I could like to it like the following example:
`myapp://callback`

I think it could look something like the following:

```
fn main() {
    tauri::Builder::default()
        .invoke_handler(tauri::generate_handler![greet])
        .register_uri_scheme_protocol("myapp", move |app, request| {
            # protocol logic here
        })
        .run(tauri::generate_context!())
        .expect("error while running tauri application");
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tauri currently doesn't directly support deep linking. A good alternative that I found was [this](https://github.com/FabianLars/tauri-plugin-oauth) rust project. After installation you can do something like the following:

```
#[tauri::command]
async fn start_oauth_server(window: Window) -> Result<u16, String> {
println!("Starting server");

start(None, move |url| {
    // Because of the unprotected localhost port, you must verify the URL here.
    // Preferebly send back only the token, or nothing at all if you can handle everything else in Rust.

    // convert the string to a url
    let url = url::Url::parse(&url).unwrap();

    // get the code query parameter
    let code = url
        .query_pairs()
        .find(|(k, _)| k == "code")
        .unwrap_or_default()
        .1;

    // get the state query parameter
    let state = url
        .query_pairs()
        .find(|(k, _)| k == "state")
        .unwrap_or_default()
        .1;

    // create map of query parameters
    let mut query_params = HashMap::new();

    query_params.insert("code".to_string(), code.to_string());
    query_params.insert("state".to_string(), state.to_string());
    query_params.insert(String::from("redirect_uri"), url.to_string());

    if window.emit("redirect_uri", query_params).is_ok() {
        println!("Sent redirect_uri event");
    } else {
        println!("Failed to send redirect_uri event");
    }
})
.map_err(|err| err.to_string())
}
```

**Update March 2023**
Thanks Zoltán Balogh for the flag

Checkout https://github.com/FabianLars/tauri-plugin-deep-link

Fabian put this up for the short term, but longterm keep an eye out on PR [#323](https://github.com/tauri-apps/tauri/issues/323)

Answer (score 2):

Please take a look at this plugin for Tauri

> https://github.com/FabianLars/tauri-plugin-deep-link

This gives you deep linking on `Windows` as well as on `Mac Os`

Answer (score 0):

**Update Feb 2024** - Tauri v2 Beta is released and now you can use the below plugin. It works perfectly with Mac as well as Windows,

Official Plugin - https://github.com/tauri-apps/plugins-workspace/tree/v2/plugins/deep-link

I have implemented this in an open source project that I am building, So you can check the below PR,

It implements deep linking on Mac. Check for info.plist file and main.rs file

https://github.com/sparrowapp-dev/sparrow-app/pull/204/files#diff-8d404d6f9439bbe1fa6b53fe13ad91614422479c67614eef823659ca2cd6dc31